# Чем может быть вызвана ошибка Warning: include() more data than requested?

Tags: php, include, jade

Столкнулся с ошибкой на одном из трех серверов.

> Warning: include(): Jade\Stream\Template::stream_read - read 233 bytes more data than requested (8425 read, 8192 max) - excess data
>   will be lost in .../vendor/Jade/Jade.php on line 319
>
> Warning: include(): Jade\Stream\Template::stream_read - read 272 bytes more data than requested (8464 read, 8192 max) - excess data
>   will be lost in .../vendor/Jade/Jade.php on line 319
>
> Warning: include(): Jade\Stream\Template::stream_read - read 104 bytes more data than requested (8296 read, 8192 max) - excess data
>   will be lost in .../vendor/Jade/Jade.php on line 319

Конфигурация серверов идентичная, версии ПО и ОС идентичные. Точнее я так думал. Воспроизвести ошибку на других серверах не удалось. Чем может быть вызвана ошибка?

index.php

```
function __autoload($class) {

    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/' . $class . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include $file;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/views/template.jade';
$template = file_get_contents($file);

$data = array(
    'data' => array(
        'city' => array(
            'name' => 'Москва',
            'code' => '800',
            'free' => '8 800 555 35 35',
            'phone' => '555 35 35',
            'soname' => 'Москве',
            'domain' => 'site.ru'
        ),
        'sro' => array(
            'name' => 'РСК',
            'link' => '',
        ),
        'fond' => '1000000',
        'summ' => '100000',
        'user' => array(
            'name' => 'Админ Сайта',
            'term' => '',
            'image' => '/images/users/admin.png',
            'email' => 'admin@site.ru',
            'phone' => '+7 800 555 35 35',
            'image_sign' => '',
        )
    )
);

$jade = new Jade\Jade();
echo $jade->render($template, $data);
```

/views/template.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(http-equiv='Content-Type', content='text/html; charset=UTF-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')
  body
    div(style='background-color: #fff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;')
      div(style='width: 620px; margin: 0 auto;')
        table(style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 10px;')
          tbody
            tr
              td
                img(src='/images/offers/logo.png')
              td
                div(style='padding-right: 10px')
                  p(style='font-size: 28px; color: #5a5a5a; text-align: right; margin: 0px;')
                    span(style='color: #999;') 8 
                      = $data['city']['code']
                    |  
                    = $data['city']['phone']
        table(style='width: 100%;  border-collapse: collapse; border-radius: 9px; margin-bottom: 0px; box-shadow: 0 30px 50px -50px gray;')
          tbody
            tr
              td.editable(style='width: 330px; padding: 25px; background-color: #205ba3; vertical-align: top; border-top-left-radius: 9px;')
                p(style='font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Trebuchet MS; color: #fff;') Взносы в наше 
                  a(style='color: #fff; font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold;', href=$data['sro']['link'], target="_blank") СРО &laquo;
                    = $data['sro']['name']
                    | &raquo;
                p(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff;') Все взносы оплачиваете напрямую в&nbsp;СРО:
                ul
                  - if (!empty($data['free']['chlen'])):
                    li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 7px;') В ПОДАРОК &mdash; вступительный взнос;
                  - else:
                    li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 7px;') 5 000 руб. &mdash; вступительный взнос;
                  - endif
                  - if (!empty($data['free']['vstup'])):
                    li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 7px;') В ПОДАРОК &mdash; членский взнос;
                  - else:
                    li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 7px;') 5 000 руб. &mdash; членский взнос;
                  - endif
                  - if (empty($data['payment_delay'])):
                    li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 7px;')= number_format($data['fond'], 0, '', ' ')
                      |  руб. &mdash; взнос в компфонд.
                  - else:
                    li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 7px;')= number_format($data['summ'], 0, '', ' ')
                      |  руб. &mdash; взнос в компфонд.*
                  - endif
                p(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff;') Стоимость наших услуг &mdash; 0 руб.
                - if (!empty($data['payment_delay'])):
                  p(style='font-size: 12px; color: #fff; margin-top: 30px; line-height: 1.5;') * оставшиеся
                    = number_format($data['fond'] - $data['summ'], 0, '', ' ')
                    | руб выплачиваются равными долями в течение 12 месяцев под 10% годовых
                - endif
              td(style='width: 200px; padding: 15px 0 15px 40px; background-color: #fefefe; vertical-align: top; border-top-right-radius: 9px; border-bottom-right-radius: 9px;', rowspan=3)
                img(style='width: 90%; border-radius: 100px;', src= $data['user']['image'])
                div(style='')
                  p(style='font-size: 13px; color: #000;')
                    span(style='font-weight: bold;')= $data['user']['name']
                    | ,
                    br
                    | ведущий специалист
                    br
                    | компании &laquo;СтройЮрист&raquo;
                  p(style='font-size: 13px; color: #000;') тел.: 
                    span(style='font-weight: bold;')= $data['user']['phone']
                  p(style='font-size: 13px; color: #000;') e-mail: 
                    a(style='font-size: 13px; color: #000;', href='mailto:'.$data['user']['email'].'?subject=%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%A1%D0%A0%D0%9E%20%D0%B2%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83%200%')= $data['user']['email']
                  img(src=$data['user']['image_sign'], style='margin: 30px 40px 0; width: 90px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 9px; background-color: #fefefe;')
                  p(style='line-height: 1.4; font-size: 13px; color: #777; margin-top: 50px;') Компания &laquo;СтройЮрист&raquo;
                    br
                    | оформляет допуски&nbsp;СРО, лицензии&nbsp;МЧС, сертификаты&nbsp;ISO,
                    br
                    | регистрирует и&nbsp;ликвидирует фирмы
                    = 'в '.$data['city']['soname']
                    br
                    | и других городах России более&nbsp;14&nbsp;лет.
                  p(style='line-height: 1.4; font-size: 13px; color: #777; margin-top: 30px;')
                    a(style='font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #777;', href='http://'.$data["city"]["domain"].'/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=kp&utm_campaign=sro&utm_term='.$data["user"]["term"]) site.ru
                  p(style='line-height: 1.7; font-size: 13px; color: #777; margin-top: 30px;') Горячая линия
                    br
                    span(style='font-weight: bold;')= $data['city']['free']
            - if (!empty($data['payment_delay'])):
              tr
                td.editable(style='width: 320px; padding: 20px 15px 20px 25px; background-color: #e94f45; border-top: 1px solid #fff; vertical-align: top;')
                  p(style='font-size: 21px; font-family: Trebuchet MS; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 10px; line-height: 1.4;') Оплати полный компфонд и&nbsp;получи 
                    span(style='font-weight: bold;') экономию 
                      = number_format(($data['fond'] - $data['summ']) / 10, 0, '', ' ')
                      |  руб,
                  p(style='font-size: 14px; color: #fff; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px; line-height: 1.5;') а&nbsp;также бессрочный сертификат &laquo;лицензия МЧС за 50 000 руб&raquo; &mdash; В ПОДАРОК!
            - else:
              tr
                td.editable(style='width: 320px; padding: 20px 15px 20px 25px; background-color: #20a13a; border-top: 1px solid #fff; vertical-align: top;')
                  p(style='font-size: 21px; font-family: Trebuchet MS; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 10px; line-height: 1.4;') Оплачивая полный компфонд
                    br
                    | Вы 
                    span(style='font-weight: bold;') экономите 
                      = number_format(($data['fond'] - $data['summ']) / 10, 0, '', ' ')
                      |  руб,
                  p(style='font-size: 14px; color: #fff; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 0px; line-height: 1.5;') В&nbsp;ПОДАРОК &mdash; бессрочный сертификат на&nbsp;получение лицензии&nbsp;МЧС за&nbsp;50&nbsp;000&nbsp;руб.
            - endif
            tr
              td.editable(style='width: 320px; padding: 20px 25px 5px; background-color: #2a83c7; border-top: 1px solid #fff; border-bottom-left-radius: 9px; vertical-align: top;')
                p(style='font-size: 21px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Trebuchet MS; color: #fff;') Наши преимущества
                ul(style='margin: 0; padding-left: 20px;')
                  li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 20px;') Дарим 3 сертификата ISO
                  li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 20px;') Дарим страховку от рисков на&nbsp;2&nbsp;млн&nbsp;руб.
                  li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 20px;') 100% гарантия «безболезненного» прохождения плановых проверок
                    // p(style='font-size: 13px; color: #eee; margin-top: 5px; line-height: 1.4;') Мы это делаем, так как у нас давние партнерские отношения с СРО
                  - if (!empty($data['reviews'])):
                    li(style='font-size: 16px; color: #fff; margin-bottom: 20px;') Клиенты
                      = 'в '.$data['city']['soname']
                      p(style='font-size: 13px; color: #eee; margin-top: 5px; line-height: 1.4;')= implode($data['reviews'], ', ')
                        | и другие
                        br
                        | Читайте отзывы на 
                        a(style='color: #eee', href='http://'.$data['city']['domain'].'/reviews/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=kp&utm_campaign=sro&utm_term='.$data['user']['term']) нашем сайте
                  - endif
        table(style='width: 100%; padding: 5px 15px 0;')
          tbody
            tr
              td(colspan=2)
                p(style='color: #000; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; font-family: Trebuchet MS; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0px;') Список необходимых документов для СРО
            tr
              td(style='width: 50%; vertical-align: top;')
                ol(style='line-height: 1.7; font-size: 12px; color: #000; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0;')
                  li Реквизиты;
                  li Свидетельства ОГРН и ИНН;
                  li Решение о создании юр. лица;
                  li Приказ о назначении директора;
                  li Выписка из ЕГРЮЛ и коды статистики;
              td(style='width: 50%;vertical-align: top;')
                ol(start=6, style='line-height: 1.7; font-size: 12px; color: #000; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0; ')
                  li Копия устава;
                  li Паспорт директора (цветная копия, фото&nbsp;и&nbsp;прописка);
                  li Договор аренды на помещение, акт&nbsp;приёма-передачи.
```

/vendor/Jade/ папка из репозитория https://github.com/pug-php/pug/tree/master/src

PHP версия 5.4.45-0+deb7u4

Comment: у сервера видимо что то с диском, так как include прочитал столько то байт получить ( к примеру 500) а получил всего 200, значит фаил не целый. Может просто повредился при копирование недозаписался грубо говоря.

Comment: В include передается не файл, а поток (https://github.com/pug-php/pug/blob/master/src/Jade/Jade.php :319), созданный функцией stream_wrapper_register(имя потока, класс обработчик) (https://github.com/pug-php/pug/blob/master/src/Jade/Jade.php :346). Обращений к файловой системе не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых это не ошибка а предпуреждение!

Ваше сообщение

> Warning: include(): Jade\Stream\Template::stream_read - read 233 bytes
>   more data than requested (8425 read, 8192 max) - excess data will be
>   lost in .../vendor/Jade/Jade.php on line 319

Перевод

> Предупреждение: include (): Jade \ Stream \ Template :: stream_read -
>   прочитано 233 больна данных чем предпологаемо (8425 прочитано, 8192 макс.)
>   - лишние данные будут потеряны в ... / vendor / Jade / Jade.php в строке 319

То есть у вас слишком большой файл. Нужно сделать его меньше и предупреждение исчезнет.
можете разделить его на 2.

Никогда не используейте include()

используйте require() or require_once()

они прервыют дальнейшее выполения скрипта и выдают сообщение что не так.
отличия то что require_once(). разрешит подключить данных скрип только 1 раз